# Are these two interchangeable with each other?

Tags: phrase-meaning

"Children are subject to colds" vs. "Children are subject*ed* to colds"

Q. I've read the answer and comments posted before, concerning a question similar to mine. But I'm not clear yet. I'd like to know whether "be subject to" and "be subjected to" can be interchangeable with each other or not. Are they? Or not?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions. When a question of yours gets closed, in this case as a duplicate, but you don't agree with the close reason, you should edit your question and wait for community members to reopen it for you. Duplicate questions will be closed and deleted because they are seen as attempting to circumvent community votes and moderation. So in this case, please edit your original question and explain what you still don't understand.

Comment: OH, I'm so sorry! I was quite in a hurry and didn't see "Edit question" button. I saw only "ask a new one". Okay, excuse my ignorance. Everybody, sorry.